# isDescendantOf method can not be found in SQL Server 2012 script - Why?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm new to SQL server 2012, and was doing well until I ran this code, taken from a Microsoft book.  I've hunted for a solution and got no where.

Any advice you can give is greatly appreciated.

```
DECLARE @AmyNodeId hierarchyid

SELECT @AmyNodeId = NodeId
 FROM  Employee
 WHERE EmployeeId = 46

SELECT NodeId.ToString() AS NodeIdPath, *
 FROM  Employee
 WHERE Employee.NodeId.isDescendantOf(@AmyNodeId) = 1
 ORDER BY NodeLevel, NodeId
```

Gives this message:

Could not find method 'isDescendantOf' for type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlHierarchyId' in assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types'

Humph!

Harvey

Comment: I was having the same issue. Turns out `isDescendantOf` is case sensitive

Answer (score 1):

This is because the method is actually case sensitive! check your case

Answer (score -1):

This fixed itself after I restarted the SQL Server 2014 Management studio.

Bugger!